# Trouble installing rJava on Mac ; trouble with JNI data types

Tags: java, r, macos, configuration, java-native-interface

## RESOLVED!!

See my solution below, in case this question helps others in the future.

## Error

As the title described, it it failing for me.  The error I'm receiving, when I attempt to `install.packages('rJava')` from inside R is (with some preceding good checks):

```
checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... yes
checking JNI data types... configure: error: One or more JNI types differ from the corresponding native type. You may need to use non-standard compiler flags or a different compiler in order to fix this.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/rJava’
```

---

## Fix Attempts

I have checked and tried the following resolutions, none of which worked for me:

- [sudo R CMD javareconf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061726/compile-rjava-on-mac-for-java-1-7?rq=1)
- [more detailed sudo R CMD javareconf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610293/how-to-get-rjava-0-9-3-to-work-on-os-x-10-7-4-with-oracle-java-1-7)
- [`export JAVA_HOME`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530601/install-rjava-configure-error-one-or-more-jni-types-differ-from-the-corresp), however in this case, I did not do the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, as it did not seem relevant to a Mac.

No such luck, with any of these attempts.

---

I **had** previously had `rJava` (and `RJDBC`) installed properly.

[Edit:  I later found out, the actual problem was upgrading to OS X 10.11, El Capitan.]

---

## Configuration

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"

> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0"
$version.string
[1] "R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)"
```

Mac OS itself:

```
System Version: OS X 10.11.1 (15B42)
```

---

Comment: The solution above got rJava to work.  However, to get things to work for RStudio (not just the command line) I also needed to follow the suggestion found in the answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally resolved this, via a solution I found [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2015-November/011712.html).

The new Mac OS X (10.11, El Capitan) has trouble with env variables.

---

The newest dev flavor of `rJava` manages to handle things correctly.  Here is what I did to resolve it:

1. Download version 0.9-8 (`rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz`) from [here](https://www.rforge.net/rJava/files/)
2. Install it from the downloaded source:

   $ R CMD INSTALL ~/Downloads/rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz

(Or wherever you put it)

That's all it took!

Answer (score 5):

> I did not do the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, as it did not seem relevant to a Mac

Yes, but a Mac has `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. If you link with `-ljvm` you have to have the directory containing `libjvm.dylib` in `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

That said, I found it more convenient to link JNI programs with `-ljli` (in `lib/jli`), because the programs linked with `-ljvm` will open a prompt to install Apple's own Java runtime when the system doesn't have it (at least they did on my and our customers' systems some while ago).

Edit: here's a link to the [dyld documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html)

Comment: Thank you for those details!  The DYLD documentation is great.  It wasn't my problem, however, as you'll see below.