# executing library('RJDBC') on R console shows java 6 installation message

Tags: java, r, macos, rjdbc

I'm trying to access a mysql database through R console using RJDBC in a mac os X system, but R console crash just after type in " > library('RJDBC') ". Immediately shows up a message indicating is necessary install the old Java 6 mac os version.

I already installed the package typing " > install.packages('RJDBC', dependencies=TRUE) "

My system have:
OSX = Mac Os X (Yosemite)
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
java 7 installed and set JAVA_HOME env variable in my ./bash_profile file.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And also if it is useful

```
R CMD javareconf
Java interpreter : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
Java version     : 1.7.0_60
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
Java compiler    : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jar
System Java on OS X

trying to compile and link a JNI progam 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers
detected JNI linker flags : -framework JavaVM
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program


JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
Java library path: 
JNI cpp flags    : 
JNI linker flags : 
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.
```

What Am I doing wrong? I even checked an old post [how to get rJava 0.9-3 to work on OS X 10.7.4 with Oracle Java 1.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610293/how-to-get-rjava-0-9-3-to-work-on-os-x-10-7-4-with-oracle-java-1-7) and the http://mailman.rz.uni-augsburg.de/pipermail/stats-rosuda-devel/ but I haven't been able to make it work, Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Hi, perhaps it is the same problem with `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing/3311983#3311983

Comment: Thx for your comment @ChristofKluß I tried but did not work

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you figured this out yet, but you need to install Java for OS X 2014-001, which is found [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US)...