# RWeka installation on mac

Tags: r, macos

I am trying to install RWeka package on mac.

OS version:

> 10.9.5

Java version installed:

> java version "1.7.0_75"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)

After executing

> install.packages("RWeka")

when I try to execute

> library(RWeka)

the following error is displayed

> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RWekajars', details:
>     call: .jinit()
>     error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1
>
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RWeka’
>   JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
>   JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
>   JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.

The output of command

> R CMD javareconf

is

> xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
>   xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
>   xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
>   xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
>   xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
>   Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
>   Java version     : 1.7.0_75
>   Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
>   Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
>   Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
>   Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
>   Non-system Java on OS X
>
> trying to compile and link a JNI program
>   detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
>   detected JNI linker flags : -L/Users/amlanroy/Library/Java/Extensions -L/Library/Java/Extensions -L/Network/Library/Java/Extensions -L/System/Library/Java/Extensions -L/usr/lib/java -L. -ljvm
>   xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
>   Unable to compile a JNI program
>
> JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
>   Java library path:
>   JNI cpp flags    :
>   JNI linker flags :
>   Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
>   Done.

Please let me know if anybody has faced the same issue and knows the solution.

Answer (score 9):

1. `sudo R CMD javareconf`
2. `install.packages("rJava",type='source')`

rJava package will solve the bugs.

Cite these from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179151/cannot-load-r-xlsx-package-on-mac-os-10-11) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610293/how-to-get-rjava-0-9-3-to-work-on-os-x-10-7-4-with-oracle-java-1-7).

Comment: I had tried the soft link suggestion and step 1 in this post from my previous notes with Java related R packages.  But my `RWeka` package installation would not succeed until I did the `rJava` install from source recommended here in step 2.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer since it solves the issue

Answer (score 7):

I had also problems with loading packages like openNLP, xlsx, RWeka, ... and got the same error message like you. But finally this command worked for me on OS X 10.11.3:

```
sudo ln -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib
```